# Unlikes fail with February 2013 breaking changes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-apps

My app presently allows users to like and unlike posts in their feed, including posts from other users/friends.

When I enable the February 2013 breaking changes, my app can still like posts from other users (POST postid/likes), but can no longer unlike the same posts (DELETE postid/likes).

Since we're not writing on the other user's wall, I wouldn't expect this to fail.

In any case, I would expect like/unlike to be treated similarly -- not have one succeed & the other fail.

Is this a known issue and/or is there a workaround?

**Update**

When February 2013 breaking changes are enabled, attempting to like another user's post succeeds, but attempting to delete returns an HTTP 403 Forbidden status, with the error:

```
"{"error":{"message":"(#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}"
```

Answer (score 4):

That sounds like a bug on our end.  Can you please file a bug on our [create bug form](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create)?